# exponent formula in Ruby without using default operator

Tags: ruby

How can use methods to calculate exponent without using `**` operator. Suppose method name `calculate(a,b)` where `a` is base and `b` is exponent value.

The value of `a` and `b` can be positive or negative integers, decimals, etc.

Thanks

Comment: If there are restrictions on `a` and/or `b`, they should be included in your question.  @WandMaker mentioned in a comment below that there had been an earlier comment that `b` is integer, but that the comment was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Would `Math.exp(b * Math.log(a))` suit your needs?  Note that while this works for non-integer `a` and `b`, it requires `a > 0`.  It is also subject to the finite precision limitations of floating point arithmetic.

---

With the restriction that `b` is integer, the following recursive solution works and is O(log `b`), i.e., asymptotically faster than repeated multiplication:

```
def calculate(a, b)
  return 1.0 / calculate(a, -b) if b < 0
  if b == 0
    1
  elsif b.even?
    calculate(a * a, b / 2)
  else
    a * calculate(a, b - 1)
  end
end
```

The value of `a` can be integer or have decimals, and positive or negative.
If you're worried about precision issues, you could also change the `return` statement to `return Rational(1, calculate(a, -b)) if b < 0`.

Comment: Thanks! It's working fine except gives me value of 81.00000000000003 when using 3 as base and 4 as exponent value.

Answer (score 2):

quite the same solution as Wand maker suggested, with different syntax for creating the Array :

```
Array.new(b, a).reduce(&:*)
```

Another solution using an enumerator (should be faster) :

```
b.times.reduce(1) { |r| r * a }
```

b.times returns an enumerator yielding the values 0 to b - 1 (resulting in b values)

the use of reduce with a block is best explained from its docs : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce

Comment: Both solutions are very nice!   Liked the way Array was created in first one.

Comment: Can you explain second one?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def calculate(a,b)
  b.times.reduce(1) { |acc, _| acc * a }
end
```

I think it's easy to read and it displays the exponent definition clearly.